# Como mostrar opciones de acuerdo al perfil de un usuario

Tags: mysql, jsp

Por favor me podrian ayudar, necesito mostrar las opciones de un sistema creado en jsp, necesito que se muestren las opciones segun el perfil que tenga el usuario.

mi menu tiene varias opciones y quiero que solo muestre las que correspondan a perfiles ADMINISTRADOR Y USUARIO

Aquí código jsp del menú.

```
<input type="text" name="txtperfil" value="ADMINISTRADOR" class="form-control">

<%
String perfil=request.getParameter("txtperfil");
try
{
    if(perfil.equals("ADMINISTRADOR"))
    {
        %>

<footer class="page-footer row cyan darken-1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="span12 tabbable">
            <h5 class="white-text"></h5>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="barraCentral.jsp" data-toggle="tab" target="centro"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Menu</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="solicitudes.jsp" data-toggle="tab" target="centro"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Solicitudes</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li><a href="administradorVuelos.jsp" data-toggle="tab" target="centro"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Administrador de Carga</a></li>
            </ul >

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a href="reportes.jsp" data-toggle="tab" target="centro"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Administrador Reportes</a></li>
            </ul >

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a href="administradorCarga.jsp" data-toggle="tab" target="centro"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span> Graficos</a></li>
            </ul > 

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="mantenedores.jsp" data-toggle="tab" target="centro">Mantenedores</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

</footer>

<%
    }
    else
    {
        if(perfil.equals("USUARIO"))
        {
            %>
<footer class="page-footer row cyan darken-1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="span12 tabbable">
            <h5 class="white-text"></h5>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="barraCentral.jsp" data-toggle="tab" target="centro"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Menu</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="solicitudes.jsp" data-toggle="tab" target="centro"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Solicitudes</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

</footer>

<%
        }
    }
}
catch(NullPointerException ex)
{
    ex.getMessage();
}
%>
```

pero no me oculta las opciones y desaparece todo el menu
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá el menú con todas las opciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
debe visualizarse la opcion Menu y Solicitudes para el perfil USUARIO y para el perfil ADMINISTRADOR Deben verse todas las opciones

Comment: ahí agregue algo que me faltaba.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado el valor de la variable perfil? Ya veo que estás inicializando el input pero eso no quiere decir que sea el valor que aparezca en la request

Comment: Prueba a quitar el if (perfil.equals("USUARIO")) (y el resto de código correspondiente) para que muestre el menú de usuario si no es un perfil ADMINISTRADOR para comprobar que pasa por ahí

Comment: Hola lo acabo de hacer pero realmente no pasa por el if, el menu no se muestra.

Comment: ¿Pasa por el else y no muestra el menú? Examina el resultado del html para ver si la sección footer está y simplemente es que no se visualiza. Pon, si puedes, el resultado en html en algún sitio público para que podamos revisarlo

Comment: El resultado si se ve pero solo sin validaciones, tengo el menu completo, pero cuando quiero mostrar solo algunas opciones usando equals es cuando no se ve nada.acabo de agregar la imagen del menu de como se ve sin validaciones.

Comment: Haz un System.out.println("Perfil del menú: " + perfil) después de String perfil=request.getParameter("txtperfil") y revisa el log a ver qué pone

Comment: Si lo realize ya y esta llegando null

Comment: Información:   Conexion exitosa :)
Información:   Perfil es:null.                                                                            Es ese el problema